# URLSearchParams fails to get first parameter when '#' is in url

Tags: javascript

This seems like a bug in this API, though I don't know where to report it. So I am posting here for help. Mozilla docs here [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

If `window.location.href` contains a `#` then `URLSearchParams.get` fails to retrieve the first search parameter

```
const location = 'http://localhost:3000/path?referrer=https://google.com';
const myURL = new URL(location).searchParams.get('referrer')
// myURL === 'https://google.com

// in one line:
(new URL('http://localhost:3000/path?referrer=https://google.com')).searchParams.get('referrer')
```

But this same example slightly tweaking the window location will fail

```
const location = 'http://localhost:3000/#/path?referrer=https://google.com';
const myURL = new URL(location).searchParams.get('referrer')
// myURL === null

// in one line
(new URL('http://localhost:3000/#/path?referrer=https://google.com')).searchParams.get('referrer')
```

This example is using `new URL(location).searchParams.get` but will yield the exact same functionality if you tweak it to using `new URLSearchParams(...).get`

Comment: that's not a bug, that's how urls work :p when you load the page in the browser, what is `window.location.search`

Comment: it's an empty string

Comment: It's not the `#` as such that is causing your problem, it's the fact that `#` appears before `?` - URL syntax is `scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]` .... see the order of ? and # - therefore the "fragment" in that url is `/path?referrer=https://google.com` - and of course, there is no "query" (or "search") part, as fragment has "taken" it all

Comment: I'd use `new URLSearchParams(new URL(location).hash.split('?')[1]).get('referrer')`

Answer (score 8):

In URL standards, `#` introduces a fragment component that has no special meaning to the transport protocol and is treated as secondary or "user specified" information whose semantics are treated as unknown. The `#` and everything following it in the URL is passed to the client application (e.g. HTML browser) without interpretation. You can access the fragment value in JavaScript using `window.location.hash`.

Any URL parameters must precede a fragment identifier or they will be included in fragment content and not parsed as parameters.

A `#` could be included in the URL path or parameters, but would need to be percentage escaped as `%23`. I would strongly advise against writing a router or creating a server side folder for static content that contains `#` in the path, even if technically possible.

Allowing users to enter `#` in form inputs would normally be handled automatically by encoding the input value with [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before submitting the form.

Data URLs that have been formulated using clear text of a particular MIME type need to percentage escape any and every `#` within the text to avoid truncating data represented by the URL.

Answer (score 4):

Just replace `#` with `/`

```
let location = 'http://localhost:3000/#/path?referrer=https://google.com';
location = location.replace('#', '/');
let myURL = new URL(location).searchParams.get('referrer')
console.log(myURL)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this issue is a bit old, but I ran into the same issue recently and created a simple function to fix the Url hash & search params:

```
function fixUrlHash(url) {
  let fixedUrl = new URL(url);
  let search = url.search;
  let hash = url.hash;
  const position = url.hash.indexOf('?');
  if(search.length <= 1 && position >= 0) {
    search = hash.substr(position);
    hash = hash.substr(0, position);
    fixedUrl.hash = hash;
    fixedUrl.search = search;
    fixedUrl.href = fixedUrl.toString();
  }
  return fixedUrl;
}
```

This simply returns a new URL object with the fixed hash & search params. After you get the fixed URL value, you can load the new URL in the browser if original URL is the browser location.

Comment: I think the function is still wrong but at least there is no more compile errors. I believe somehow the url is worng e.g. fixedUrl.href